# .NET version with 64-bit versus 32-bit assemblies

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

What version of .NET (64-bit vs. 32-bit) will be loaded if some of the assemblies referenced in an app are compiled with 32-bit only (instead of AnyMachine) setting?  Will the app still run as 64-bit or will it be forced to run as 32-bit if at least one of the referenced assemblies is compiled as 32-bit only?  The app is running .NET 3.5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bit-ness is determined by the Platform Target setting on the EXE.  There is no mechanism to ensure that a EXE that references a 32-bit only assembly will be forced to run in 32-bit mode as well.  The assembly will simply fail to load with a BadImageFormatException.

If your program has a dependency on such a DLL then you *must* force the Platform Target on your EXE project from AnyCPU to x86.

Comment: Would it fail at the very beginning of the app or when the assembly is acually used?

Comment: When it is used.  Which could be close to the beginning.

Answer (score 5):

The application will be forced to run as 32-bit

Comment: And if the assembly is dynamically loaded, and the process is 64bit, the 32bit assembly will fail to load.

Comment: And if the referenced assembly is compiled as AnyCPU but making use of  an unmanaged DLL, then it will fail to run if you don't provide a 64bit version of the unmanaged DLL

Comment: Isn't the bit-ness of the process determined by the main executable, and if that module references assemblies of a different bit-ness, those will fail to load, not force the process to a different bit-ness? For instance, if you create a executable and compile it for AnyCPU, but it references a bunch of 32-bit assemblies, the process will run fine on a 32-bit OS, but fail to load the additional assemblies on a 64-bit OS?